# How to install TMS FNC UI components into Visual Studio Code for TMS WEB Core Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tms, tms-web-core, tms-fnc-ui-pack

When I installed the [TMS WEB Core](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmswebcore.asp) [extension in Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tmssoftware.tmswebcore), it installed a whole bunch of different components:

[image: TMS WEB Core Tool Palette in Visual Studio Code]

But I don't see any [TMS FNC UI Pack](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfncuipack.asp) components. I know they are available for WEB:

> Universal powerful, feature-rich UI controls in 1 component set for VCL, FMX, LCL and WEB core apps.

I [downloaded](https://download.tmssoftware.com/download/TMSFNCUIPACKVSCTrial.ZIP) [TMS FNC UI Pack for Visual Studio Code](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfncuipack.asp#downloads), but I don't know how to install it into Visual Studio Code. There isn't a VSIX file, so I can't install via VSIX:
[image]

What's the correct procedure for TMS FNC UI? And is it the same on all platforms (Windows, MacOS, Linux)?